# How does one run the VS 2010 Pro Command line choices as admin?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-8

Visual Studio 2010, running under Windows 8, has several command line choices under Visual Studio Tools.  I can't find the name of any of these so I can set the .exe for one or all of them to always run as administrator.

Nor, can I find the location of the cmd file called by Run to do this.

The problem I need to solve is to run aspnet_regiis -i without getting the error that it won't run because elevation is needed.

FYI, I'm an admin on my Windows 8 laptop because I'm the only account on it, default is admin.  So when I run an executable it should ALREADY be running as an admin.

I should mention why I have to run aspnet_regiis -i and that is, I'm not getting any .aspx Handler Mappings in IIS 8.  So, naturally the defaut.aspx file of the Dot Net Nuke site I'm trying to work with won't fire up.

Other forums are no help.

My guess is I need to locate the command line executable within VS 2010 or the overall one that is targeted from Run and set these to run as admin.  Then I should be able to run aspnet_regiis -i and get the mappings I need in IIS 8.

For those familiar with IIS 8, I've already edited the applicationHost.config file and set the handlers and modules entries in the system.web tag lockouts from "Deny" to "Allow" -- some but not all the handler mappings display.

There's a mouthful :)  Anyone familiar with this issue?

I'm running Windows 8 Home, 6 GB RAM, VS 2010 SP 1, IIS 8 with all options selected.  Again, to make sure installing VS 2010 and enabling IIS 8 didn't happen in the wrong order, I've already disabled IIS, restarted and then re-enabled IIS hoping this would handle it.

No Joy.

Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 2):

Just run VS 2010 as admin. All of the tools will then run as admin.

1. Right click VS 2010 shortcut
2. Select "run as administrator"